# Set delay between tasks in group in Celery

Tags: python, celery

I have a python app where user can initiate a certain task.

The whole purpose of a task is too execute a given number of POST/GET requests with a particular interval to a given URL.

So user gives N - number of requests, V - number of requests per second.

How is it better to design such a task taking into account that due to a I/O latency the actual r/s speed could bigger or smaller.

First of all I decided to use Celery with Eventlet because otherwise I would need dozen of works which is not acceptable.

My naive approach:

- Client starts a task using task.delay()
- Inside task I do something like this:

  ```
  @task
  def task(number_of_requests, time_period):
     for _ in range(number_of_requests):
         start = time.time()
         params_for_concrete_subtask = ...
         # .... do some IO with monkey_patched eventlet requests library
         elapsed = (time.time() - start)
         # If we completed this subtask to fast
         if elapsed < time_period / number_of_requests:
             eventlet.sleep(time_period / number_of_requests)
  ```

A working example is [here](https://github.com/Glueon/celery_examples/blob/master/tasks.py#L38-L60).

if we are too fast we try to wait to keep the desired speed. If we are too slow it's ok from client's prospective. We do not violate requests/second requirement. But will this resume correctly if I restart Celery?

I think this should work but I thought there is a better way.
In Celery I can define a task with a particular rate limit which will almost match my needs guarantee. So I could use Celery `group` feature and write:

```
@task(rate_limit=...)
def task(...):
    #

task_executor = task.s(number_of_requests, time_period)
group(task_executor(params_for_concrete_task) for params_for_concrete_task in ...).delay()
```

But here I hardcode the the rate_limit which is dynamic and I do not see a way of changing it. I saw an example:

```
  task.s(....).set(... params ...)
```

But I tried to pass `rate_limit` to the `set` method it it did not work.

Another maybe a bettre idea was to use Celery's periodic task scheduler. With the default implementation periods and tasks to be executed periodically is fixed.

I need to be able to dynamically create tasks, which run periodically a given number of times with a specific rate limit. Maybe I need to run my own Scheduler which will take tasks from DB? But I do not see any documentation around this.

Another approach was to try to use a `chain` function, but I could not figure out is there a delay between tasks parameter.

Comment: Using a chain will wait for the previous job to finish, is that what you want?

Comment: @Maresh They will run sequentially without a delay between them. Delay is dynamic. It depends on how long the task was executing and the maximum speed specified by client. So if it took 1 second for a task to run and my desired speed is 0.5 task/second I can't run the second task immediately. The second task needs to wait for 1 second. On the  other hand if it took 2 seconds to run then the next task can run right away. I can return a `freeze_time`  from a task and pass to the next one so it freezes if needed. But I do not like that solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to adjust the rate_limit dynamically you can do it using the following code. It is also creating the chain() at runtime. 
Run this you will see that we successfully override the rate_limit of 5/sec to 0.5/sec.

> test_tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery, signature, chain
import datetime as dt

app = Celery('test_tasks')
app.config_from_object('celery_config')

@app.task(bind=True, rate_limit=5)
def test_1(self):
    print dt.datetime.now()


app.control.broadcast('rate_limit',
                       arguments={'task_name': 'test_tasks.test_1',
                                  'rate_limit': 0.5})

test_task = signature('test_tasks.test_1').set(immutable=True)

l = [test_task] * 100

chain = chain(*l)
res = chain()
```

I also tried to override the attribute from within the class, but IMO the rate_limit is set when the task is registered by the worker, that is why the .set() has no effects. I'm speculating here, one would have to check the source code.

**Solution 2**

Implement your own waiting mechanism using the end time of the previous call, in the chain the return of the function is passed to the next one.

So it would look like this:

```
from celery import Celery, signature, chain
import datetime as dt
import time

app = Celery('test_tasks')
app.config_from_object('celery_config')

@app.task(bind=True)
def test_1(self, prev_endtime=dt.datetime.now(), wait_seconds=5):
    wait = dt.timedelta(seconds=wait_seconds)
    print dt.datetime.now() - prev_endtime
    wait = wait - (dt.datetime.now() - prev_endtime)
    wait = wait.seconds
    print wait
    time.sleep(max(0, wait))
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    print now
    return now

#app.control.rate_limit('test_tasks.test_1', '0.5')
test_task = signature('test_tasks.test_1')

l = [test_task] * 100

chain = chain(*l)
res = chain()
```

I think this is actually more reliable than the broadcast.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out. But it should be 'test_tasks.test_1' instead of `test_tasks.mytask`?

Comment: Yea, good catch :) I just thought of another way which might be better. I'll edit later today

Comment: Checkout the other solution.

Comment: yes next solution looks like the thing I implemented.  So I just create a different signature like `test_task = test_tasks.test_1.s(wait_seconds=10)`? It will add a delay between the first run, but this not that bad.

Comment: Yes. If you want to prevent the first run to wait just pass an old prev_endtime (now - X seconds) to the function.

Comment: Also you could use the line commented in solution2 to change rate_limit at runtime for the current worker which is more reliable that the broadcast, but its limited, it depends on you setup/goals I guess. And btw, signature is more convenient than .s(), because it doesnt need the body of the function, which is useful if you want to separate the tasks code from the flow app.

Comment: Is it possible to add a callback to the chain when the chain is execution has finished? To do some clean up.
Right now i just added the clean up task at the end of the chain, but what I do not like is that the clean up task will receive the first argument from the last working task which is a bit annoying.

Comment: just set you last task as immutable if you want to ignore it. `.set(immutable=True)`. You can also do stuff like that: `chain(chain(), task())`